# Need to store form data from wordpress in database WITH current active username

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, forms

I have a page where users can enter their kids height and track it as they grow. Is it possible to store form data with the username that entered it, and allow multiple entries?  Ideally I would feed this data to a cool JS chart and display it.  Any recommendations or tips?  I can only get the form data to store completely on its own, using this tutorial:

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html

Help appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide us with the code sample you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can request the logged in username from Wordpress, and save it in your DB indeed.
You can find more info via this link:

[codex.wordpress.org->get_currentuserinfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)